# What am I doing wrong with this halftone border?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I am trying to add a halftone border to this image (I'm short on time, the image I have already has a blurred edge and I won't be able to get the uneditied image on time) in PS for DTF printing and it's applying the effect to the whole image instead of just the border. I've been going crazy trying to figure this out, please help!

[image]

This is what my layers look like

[image]

EDIT: And this is the effect I want

[image]

EDIT 2: Changed wording bc I was typing in a panic

Answer (score 1):

A halftone is not supposed to be transparent, so do not add any adjustment layer to it.

Look at the difference between these two images. The one on the left has no transparency on the layer itself. The one on the right has gradient transparency.

[image]

In order to do the effect, I do not have Ps right now, but in general:

1. Make a new rectangular grayscale gradient from **pure black to pure white**. You do not want those white dots you have on your image.
2. Transform it to a 1-bit image with Halftone. Play with it.
3. Put it over your image with "If lighter".

[image]

P.S. In order to have a smooth dot, the source image needs to be at high resolution. If you can make it 600-1200 PPI.

---

Using 1 bit image can make the edges a bit rough on small resolutions.

[image]

In that case, you could make the gradient at a high scale, make it halftone, convert it to grayscale again, and resample it. But you can not use it with "If Lighter" blending mode, but you can now use it as a mask for a flat white color layer.

<sub>https://www.pexels.com/es-es/foto/mujer-sonriente-vistiendo-camiseta-rosa-con-cuello-redondo-1642228/</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Just kinda guessing without the file....

- Remove the G-blur (edges won't be faded to transparency and will have the halftone effect.
- Create a [clipping mask](https://www.google.com/search?q=photohsop%20clipping%20mask&oq=photohsop%20clipping%20mask&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIJCAEQABgNGIAEMgkIAhAAGA0YgAQyCQgDEAAYDRiABDIJCAQQABgNGIAEMgkIBRAAGA0YgAQyCQgGEAAYDRiABDIJCAcQABgNGIAEMgkICBAAGA0YgAQyCQgJEAAYDRiABNIBCDM3MTJqMGo3qAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) of Layer 2 so it only effects the layer below it.
- You *may* need to add a layer mask to Layer 2 (hiding the interior of the layer) if you only want edges to have the halftone appearance.. and then blur that layer *mask* if needed.

Ultimately, you want the halftone layer to essentially have the reverse appearance .....

[image]

Whether this is done on the layer its self (destructive) or via a layer mask (non-destructive) doesn't really matter for the appearance.